# merging two SQL SELECT statements returning values from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how would i merge the following two sql select statements?

```
//select all rows from our userlogin table where the emails match
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                       FROM userlogin 
                      WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");
$num1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);
//if the number of matchs is 1
if($num1 == 1) {
  //the email address supplied is taken so display error message
  echo '<p class="c7">The <b>e-mail</b> address you supplied is already taken. Please go <a href="register.php">back</a> and try again.<br><img src="resources/img/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="15"></p>';
  include_once ("resources/php/footer.php");        
  exit; 
} else {
  //select all rows from our userlogin_fb table where the emails match
  $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                         FROM userlogin_fb 
                        WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");
  $num2 = mysql_num_rows($res2);
  //if the number of matchs is 1
  if($num2 == 1) {
    //the email address supplied is taken so display error message
    echo '<p class="c7">The <b>e-mail</b> address you supplied is already taken. Please go <a href="register.php">back</a> and try again.<br><img src="resources/img/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="15"></p>';
    include_once ("resources/php/footer.php");      
    exit;   
  } else {;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
//select all rows from our userlogin table where the emails match
$query = sprintf("SELECT 1 
                    FROM userlogin 
                   WHERE `email` = '%s'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 1
                    FROM userlogin_fb 
                   WHERE `email` = '%s' ",
                   $email, $email);
$res1 = mysql_query($query);
$num1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);
//if the number of matchs is 1
if($num1 >= 1) {
  //the email address supplied is taken so display error message
  echo 'The <b>e-mail</b> address you supplied is already taken. Please go <a href="register.php">back</a> and try again.<br><img src="resources/img/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="15"></p>';
  include_once ("resources/php/footer.php");        
  exit; 
}
```

Comment: and the difference between UNION and UNION ALL is that UNION ALL maintains all duplicates.

Comment: @stivlo: Yes, I just left a similar comment for Bjoem's answer.  `UNION` (all or otherwise) also requires the same number of columns and data types at each SELECT clause.  `UNION ALL` is also faster than `UNION` because it's not removing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways of doing it (just for the SQL part):

Solution 1: UNION

```
SELECT * 
FROM userlogin 
WHERE email = '$email'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM userlogin_fb 
WHERE email = '$email';
```

Both tables basically need the same fields, otherwise adjust the `SELECT *`-part of the statement.

Solution 2: Link the tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM userlogin AS T1 
JOIN userlogin_fb AS T2 ON T1.email = T2.email
WHERE T1.email = '$email';
```

To start with, I'd prefer (1), because (2) might be affected by the table design.

Comment: `UNION` will remove duplicates, when `UNION ALL` will not -- but we also don't know that the tables are identical.  And YUCK -- no ANSI-89 join syntax; ANSI-92 only please.